# How to create shadow effect of UIScrollView, UITableView when scrolling?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a UITableView and I would like it ho have the same effect when scrolling as the picture. (Shadow below UINavigationBar and above of UITableView)

How can I do this?:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a view on the top of the uitable with a custom background.
See this related question: [Light gray background in "bounce area" of a UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166236/light-gray-background-in-bounce-area-of-a-uitableview)
In your case you could have an image instead of a solid color.

Comment: I also found this: http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/08/adding-shadow-effects-to-uitableview.html