# Continue alternating row colors in the "bounce area" of a UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uikit

In Weather.app on iPhone, scrolling past the bounds of the Hourly tableview continues to show the alternating table cells, just without any text inside of them (see image below). I was wondering how I could replicate this look. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166236/light-gray-background-in-bounce-area-of-a-uitableview) provides one solution, but I was hoping there was a more efficient way then just adding an image of blank cells above my tableview.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `headerView` and `footerView` properties of the UITableView. These allow you to specify custom UIViews that will be placed before and after your content cells.

So, you should initialize a UIView with some dummy inner views with alternating colors. The height for this UIView should be equal to `tableView.frame.size.height`. then just do:

```
tableView.headerView = headerViewWithFakeColors;
tableView.footerView = footerViewWithFakeColors;
```

Also, you will also need to change the `contentInset` property so that these fake header&footer views are only visible when the user is bouncing (with contentInset you can control the point where the tableview starts bouncing)

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(headerViewWithFakeColors.frame.size.height, 0, -footerViewWithFakeColors.frame.size.height, 0);
```