# UISearchController UISearchBar background

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

When adding a UISearchController to a UITableView header view, it is impossible to set the background behind the UISearchBar.

The second picture is showing the view when dragging to the bottom.

[image: Normal]
[image: Dragging]

The UITableView is set in the Storyboard without any headers.

```
self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];

// Setup appearance
self.searchController.searchBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
self.searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = BLUE;
self.searchController.searchBar.tintColor = RED;

// Setup logic
self.searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = @[ NSLocalizedString(@"students", nil), NSLocalizedString(@"professors", nil), NSLocalizedString(@"rooms", nil) ];
self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;

self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
```

I tried adding the background to the storyboard, to the superview, the UITableView, and manually to the UISearchBar.

More code available [here](https://github.com/thegameg/EpiTime-iOS/blob/master/EpiTime/Groups/ETGroupsViewController.m).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
UIView* topview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -480, self.view.frame.size.width, 480)];
topview.backgroundColor = BLUE;

[self.tableView addSubview:topview];
```

I have tested with a `UITableViewController` and it works fine.

Inspired from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1485023/2433921)

Comment: I used [this hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1166236/light-gray-background-in-bounce-area-of-a-uitableview/23385790#23385790) to add an empty view. Thanks