# iOS SearchDisplayController prevents tableview from background color change (background stays gray)

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, searchdisplaycontroller

This might be a bug in iOS 7:
I used storyboard to drag in **Search Bar and Search Display Controller** in my tableview controller. The background color of my tableview is altered after that.
I am using an example from AppCoda's "how-to-add-search-bar-uitableview" to demo this issue. I only changed the example code with 1-line add-on in `ViewDidLoad`:

```
   [_tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

See my screenshots here:

1. The bottom of the tableview has already changed to black: 
   [image]
2. But the top stays as gray though tableview's background was set to black: [image]
   This only happens when I drag in "Search Bar and Search Display Controller". If I remove the "Search Display Controller" from storyboard, it's all good.

Comment: I was working on this all day. I tried with dragging in only the search bar and there is no problem. See screenshot here (https://www.dropbox.com/s/dnlqajb3wz9vdvo/2014-04-11%2022.45.40.png). However, anytime I add SearchDisplayController even programmatically, the issue will be able to be reproduced.

Comment: If you want to reproduce this bug, just checkout the example I used here "http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-add-search-bar-uitableview/" with tableview's background color change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using a `UISearchDisplayController` in a `UITableViewController`, it is very important to remember that you are dealing with two table views.

So when you drag a "Search Bar and Search Display Controller" into a `UITableView` (and assuming you are doing this drag in a `UIStoryboard`), you are actually added another `UITableView` that, when activated, must be managed by code in your `UITableViewController` file in the same manner as any other `UITableView`.

Consider this:

The UITableView that represents the complete data set can be called using `self.tableView` (or as you have written, the synthesised `_tableView`).

The UITableView that represents the filtered data set (filtered using your search criteria) can be called using `self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView`

If you'd like both your default `UITableView` and search `UITableView` background colour to display a black colour, I can suggest this code (works in a TVC in my app)...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.tableView setBackgroundView:nil];
    [self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView setBackgroundView:nil];
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
}
```

...

**UPDATE**

Now that I have finished my **long-winded lecture**, I agree that there is in fact a "bug" of sorts in Xcode. If you delete the original `UISearchBar` and then add a new one to a `UITableViewController`, before you connect it, do a Build & Run. A black background is visible below **and above** the table view. It is only after you set the `UISearchBar` as an outlet for the `UISearchDisplayController` that the black background is "replaced" with a grey background.

So the solution...

With thanks to [Olof](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283153/olof)'s answer to [Different background colors for the top and bottom of a UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114587/different-background-colors-for-the-top-and-bottom-of-a-uitableview).

**REPLACE** the code I have written above with this code, at the end of your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    ...<other code>...

    CGRect frame = self.tableView.bounds;
    frame.origin.y = -frame.size.height;
    UIView* viewBackgroundBlack = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [viewBackgroundBlack setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [self.tableView addSubview:viewBackgroundBlack];

    [self.tableView setBackgroundView:nil];
    [self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView setBackgroundView:nil];
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
}
```

Comment: I tried with that but it doesn't seem to work. Wonder if you have tried out and make it work. Let me know where you put this code.

Comment: Read this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/backgroundView

Comment: Include the line '[searchTableView setBackgroundView:nil];'

Comment: Also the URL for the AppCode tutorial you refer to appears to be no longer valid - try this instead - http://www.appcoda.com/search-bar-tutorial-ios7/

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried that but it still doesn't work. I put these 4 lines in ViewDidLoad but there is no change: 
    [self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    UITableView *searchTableView = self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView;
    [searchTableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [searchTableView setBackgroundView:nil];

Comment: I am pretty sure this answer doesn't really work. I've tried a couple of times.

Comment: You are pretty sure the answer does not work for you, and yet you ignore the fact that the code I have provided works for me? I am unable to assist unless you provide code of your own - this is necessary for me to be able to make a proper assessment and point out where you may be able to make changes to resolve your problem.

Comment: Please use the code in appcoda.com/search-bar-tutorial-ios7 and add the changes that you provide.

Comment: This is the download link: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2857188/RecipeAppSearchBar.zip

Comment: OK, you are correct! I agree, you have found an unusual bug in Xcode. However I note this - after I added a `UISearchBar` to the `UITableViewController`, and before setting the delegate to the TVC and connecting to `UISearchDisplayController`, I did a Build & Run. The background was black! It is only after making the search bar an outlet of the search display controller, that the "top area" grey colour returns.

Comment: And I have also found a solution to your problem... see amended response to your question...

Comment: Nice! That's the solution. I think we can safely remove these 4 lines:
[self.tableView setBackgroundView:nil];
    [self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView setBackgroundView:nil];
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

Comment: I thought that too... and that was my answer for a few hours, but when I tried it in my own app, only the area above the table view was coloured. So I expect you will find those four lines are still required.

Answer (score 3):

The problem arise when `UISearchBar` set as header view from Storyboard. Wrapping `UISearchBar` in `UIView` seems to solve the problem but brings other problems regarding compatibility with `UISearchDisplayController`.

I hacked into UI and basically found that `UITableView` positions a stub view between its top edge and header view and it's the first subview in `UITableView` hierarchy. Changing its background color won't work because it's updated on each scroll position change.

So my solution is to simply zero the `alpha` value for it. Therefore we delegate the background color to `UITableView` itself. It works perfectly fine on iOS 7.1 and seems to be a light-weight patch in this situation.

```
//
// Fix background color bug
// This patch can be applied once in viewDidLoad if you use UITableViewController
// http://stackoverflow.com/q/23026531/351305
//
- (void)_fixSearchBarHeaderViewBackgroundColorBug {
    // First subview in UITableView is a stub view positioned between table's top edge and table's header view.
    UIView* stubView = [self.tableView.subviews firstObject];

    // Make sure it's stub view and not anything else
    if([NSStringFromClass([stubView class]) isEqualToString:@"UIView"]) {
        // Set its alpha to zero to use background color from UITableView
        stubView.alpha = 0.0f;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to use: `self.tableView.backgroundView = [UIView new];`. It worked！

Comment: None of the above ideas worked, except for yours. Cheers