# Background colors in UITableViewController with UISearchbar

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

please look at the following screenshot.

[image: different colors tones]

It shows a UITableviewController with a UISearchdisplayController in the view header. I have set the background color of the table view to a somehow white color (see the below area). However the area above the UISearchbar does not have the same color (gray). How can I set / change this color? I tried different approaches like:

- Adding additional subview
- Seachbar background color
- ...

But till now i have had no success. Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Adding a subview to the table view is how I've solved this issue. Update your question with your attempt.

Comment: I used

`UIView *view = [UIView new];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redcolor];
[self.tableView addSubView:view];` without any success.

Answer (score 3):

So i found the issue:

I was using:

```
self.tableView.tableViewHeader = self.searchDisplayController.searchbar;
```

Now I am using an aditional view with the searchbar as subview:

```
UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.searchDisplayController.searchbar.frame];
[v addSubview:self.searchDisplayController.searchbar];
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = v;
```

Everything works fine now, the gray color is gone and the backgorundColors are equal.

Comment: Possible duplicate - have a read through this... http://stackoverflow.com/a/23026733/1883707

Answer (score 0):

you can play with

```
[[UISearchBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

or

```
[[UISearchBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```