# UIViewController with UITableView and UISearchBar gap issue

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have a `UIViewController` with a `UITableView` and a `UISearchBar` inside. As soon as the searchbar becomes first responder, there's a small gap between the searchbar and the tableview.

[image: Initial state][image: Searchbar becomes first responder]

There's no gap when the `UISearchBar` is a subview of the `UIViewController` view instead of being a subview of the `UITableView`.

[image: Initial state][image: Searchbar becomes first responder]

Obviously, one issue with that approach is that the searchbar stick to the top and doesn't scroll along with other cells, which is not desired.

Any ideas?

**Edit:**

Two first images correspond to the `UISearchBar` being a child of the `UITableView`, where the gap is occurring.

Last two images correspond to the `UISearchBar` being a child of the `UIViewController` view, in which case there's no gap.

Comment: Could you please make it a little more clear as to which configuration is attached to each image example?

Comment: Done. Do you have an idea what could cause this gap?

Comment: See answer... does that assist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The gap is occurring when setting `UINavigationBar` translucent property to `NO`. Setting it to `YES` resolve the issue. Animation is smooth again and there's no gap between `UISearchBar` and `UITableView`. I can't explain why, and it appears to be a bug on Apple side as it is easy to reproduce by creating a sample project.

Comment: 3 years and many Xcode/iOS versions later... this is still a problem, and this fix still works.

Comment: Mine was `true`/`YES` and setting it to `false`/`NO` fixed it

Comment: Hii translucent property is solve my issue, but it change my navigation bar color so can you have any other solution ? Thank You

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue, however none of the above solutions worked. As per @plgrenier answer, the translucency of the status bar caused the issue.

One way I handled this was to use the search delegates to switch the translucency:

```
#pragma mark - Table Search Delegates
- (void) searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{   
      [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:YES];
}
-(void) searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
  [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit difficult without seeing the code, but perhaps try setting the uisearchbar as the uitableview's header view instead of adding it as a subview.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it may have something to do with the fact that in a `UITableView` and using a `UITableViewController`, you can pull the entire table view and search bar down to reveal a space behind, a background.

When you are inserting a `UISearchBar` and `UITableView` into a `UIView`, the "pull-down" UI is not inherited (as it is unique to `UITableViewController`) so the "hint" of a "pull-down" space is not there.

To check this and hopefully solve your problem, read my answer to this previous [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23026531/ios-searchdisplaycontroller-prevents-tableview-from-background-color-change-bac/23026733#23026733) by implementing the `UITableView` properties `setBackgroundView` and `setBackgroundColor`.

Comment: Gap is still here, but black colored. Gap size seems to be equal to statusbar.