# Greyed tableview background even after searching is completed

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am having UISearchBar in my iOS Table view application. I am able to search for words.
When I search for words, Search bar comes to front with full screen and greyed background of table view.
After searching, and clicked on cancel, still the greyed background doesn't disappear in the table view. Please see the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Put some code .. how u are implementing UISearchBar

Comment: see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23026531/ios-searchdisplaycontroller-prevents-tableview-from-background-color-change-bac) may be help with you