# SwiftUI Different background colors for the top and bottom of a List

Tags: ios, swift, list, swiftui

I want make different background colors for the top and bottom of a list.

When I use UIKIT I Do like this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114587/different-background-colors-for-the-top-and-bottom-of-a-uitableview)

Now I use SwiftUI. And I have no idea how can I make this..

thanks!

Comment: Good question, I remember trying and failing to do this before

Comment: do u mean different colors for multiple rows?

Comment: @JaisonThomas 
No, I'm not.
I want different list background colors

Comment: just to make sure [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/56523389) isn't what you're looking for ?

Comment: @JaisonThomas Sorry. No. It's not what I want
I want like this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2471852/11087662)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `UIView` to the header.  I have found a height of 400 is large enough to cover the pull down without seeing the top edge.

```
 var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            List(data, id: \.self) { data in
                Text("\(data)")
            }
            .onAppear {
                let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: -400, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 400.0))
                headerView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
                UITableView.appearance().addSubview(headerView)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Title", displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
```

[image]

---

If you want a different background color below the List then add another `UIView` to change the backgroundView:

```
let backgroundView = UIView()
backgroundView.backgroundColor = .black
UITableView.appearance().backgroundView = backgroundView
```

[image]